# Use SAML SSO in IONIC App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, saml-2.0, adfs

I have already implemented OAuth for ionic app using ADFS 4.0 as the service provider.

Now, there are some internal web sites which are added as links inside the app which are registered via ADFS SAML.

I have the following parameters from ADFS Registration

```
Authentication protocol: SAML

Relying party identifier: https://goto.abc.com

SAML Assertion Consumer endpoint: https://goto.abc.com/auth/postResponse (POST)

SAML Logout endpoint: https://goto.abc.com/auth/logout (Redirect)

Hash algorithm: SHA-256

Signature verification certificate: self-signed from goto.abc.com.
```

Is there any implementation which can use these parameters or can exchange oauth and SAML tokens to allow access to those websites.

Comment: hi sourav, who created this endpoint  https://goto.abc.com/auth/postResponse for you ?

Comment: @ParthDoshi Our DevOps team who manage all the SAML Registrations

Comment: hi sourav ..can u pls tell me your email address. I had some doubt and wanted to contact u