# Storing SAML Assertion on mobile app and use them for user session

Tags: android, saml

Trying to set the flow of SSO inside a mobile App. Here is what the flow is

- SP resource URL is presented to CustomChromeTabs (Android)
- SP Redirects to IDP for authentication
- IDP presents login screen
- User adds credentials and submits back to IDP
- IDP check for the credentials and sends back SAML Assertion to SP
- SP process the response and as it trusts IDP, converts SAML Assertion to access token
- SP redirects token back to mobile app. CustomChromeTab store it in cookie for further resource requests

Problem

- Due to security issues, storing access token inside a cookie is not advisable

Solution

1. Store encrypted SAML assertion inside secured android keystore system

Questions

1. Is it possible to store SAML assertions on client side (here mobile app) and use them later to get access token from SP?
2. How expirations of these SAML Assertion works?

Comment: You're already doing SAML -> OAuth... Don't take a step backwards. Rather than storing the Access Token (which is supposed to be short-lived), use a persistent grant in the SP and store the refresh token. You can then use that to get a new Access Token whenever you need it (depending on the SP, I suppose).

Comment: @AndrewK. yes this can be done. But wanted to know all of my options. Is it possible to save SAML Assertion? how to manage its expiry?

Comment: One of the SAML specification's "SHOULD" statements for a SAML SP is that it has a mechanism by which it tracks assertions, and does not allow replay of assertions that it has already received for at least the validity period of the assertion. This requirement exists specifically because the assertion is handled by the browser, and the assertion could be saved and reused by a bad actor. So, even if you could save it, the SP should reject it.